# How to draw a uml self association using Jointjs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, uml, jointjs

Is there a way to draw a self association in UML class diagramm using JointJs? e.g using the official example here.[uml jointjs demo example](https://resources.jointjs.com/demos/umlcd)

Comment: In your link I don't see any self-refeence.

Comment: @ThomasKilian  You're right. But I want to add that relationship to the example.

Comment: Is joint.js based on backbone.js?

Comment: @TJ yes.. it's based on `backbone` and `lodash`